# Loop Pandas table in Django template

Tags: python, django, pandas, python-itertools

I have a Pandas table which filled with values in my view. This view send this data to my template. Unfortunately I can't loop the values despite I can it in python shell. I attach my table and my attempt:

**My table (MyTable):**

```
ID    day      data
_|___________|_____
0| 2017-01-01|100.0|
1| 2017-01-02|99.8 |
2| 2017-01-03|90.0 |
```

**My attempt:**

```
{%for i, b in MyTable.itertools() %}
            <td>{{b['day']}}</td><td> {{b['data']}}</td>
{%endfor%}
```

**I got the following error message:**

```
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'MyTable.iterools()'
```

In python shell (where I testing) I could loop the table by the method below.
How can I loop my pandas table in Django template? Thank you in advance.

Comment: is that a model ?? please post the code of your view and model

Comment: @Exprator The table is a result a left join: `MyTable = pd.merge(day, data, how='left', on=['day', 'day'])`

Comment: do the calculation in view what you are trying to do in template and then send them as context to the template and display it

Comment: Yes, I did the calculation and I sending `MyTable` as a context but I can't loop it.

Comment: even the looping has to be done inside view

Comment: Yes the loop is working in my view but I think has to be a solution to loop it my template. I don't want to loop again in my view and to it again in template

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As is clearly documented, Django template language doesn't allow `()` or `[]`. Functions are called automatically and the dot notation is used for item lookups.

Also, a Pandas datatable doesn't have an `itertools` method; you probably meant `itertuples` which works like this:

```
{% for b in MyTable.itertuples %}
        <td>{{ b.day }}</td><td> {{ b.data }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read your pandas Table data to list

like this：

```
context["data"]= [{"id": 0, "day": "2017-01-01", "data": "100.0"}, {...}, {...}]

return render_to_response(template_name, context)
```

in html:

```
{% for d in data %}
    <h1>{{ d.id, d.day, d.data }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```