# Trying to Display Pandas DataFrame in Django HTML Output

Tags: python, html, django

I am currently trying to display a dataframe in HTML output with Django. Currently I have designed a view that takes in a couple csv files, runs some functions on them and then outputs a results dataframe. I am now trying to get this results dataframe to be on my html output.

**views.py:**

```py
results_html = results.to_html(index=False)
return render(request, 'home.html', {'results_html': results_html})
```

**home.html:**

```html
<html>
  <body>
      <table>{{results_html|safe}}</table>
   </body>
</html>
```

My home.html is in the templates folder within my overall app folder. I am trying to get this table to be displayed after clicking a button and also allow the ability to add design to the table to make it more visually appealing.

I have been researching on this site and other and tried their solutions and the table still doesn't output.

Comment: It seems like you're nesting a table inside of a table. Maybe try and remove the existing `<table></table>` tags and use `{{results_html|safe}}` directly?

Comment: @GrahamHealy I tried that and it still doesn't output anything. Everything else on the page outputs except that

Comment: If you add `print(results_html)` what does it contain? It could be that the `| safe` context processor is doing something to remove the value?

Comment: @GrahamHealy add that to the function in views.py? that did nothing, also removing | safe from the html code also doesnt change anything

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48762617/loop-pandas-table-in-django-template ?

Comment: Is your pandas dataframe empty? I tried with a local django application and your code is working for me.

Comment: @GrahamHealy figured it out, it is with my URLs.py as when i go to output/ exptention the table shows up. Do you know how to get this just to show up with a button click on the main page?

Comment: You could use a URL query param to have a boolean value for whether to display the table or not and then the button would just be a link to the URL e.g. `/foo/bar?showTable=true`.

Comment: @GrahamHealy awesome thank you i got it! One last thing, is there a way that i can format this table to show up nicer on the html page? Do i do that on the html code?

Comment: Great to hear @Tristan, you can pass in some option classes as a string to `to_html` which I would then style via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the pandas code in the view , it is difficult to give you an answear. Try to add in your code escape=False

```
results_html = results.to_html(index=False,escape=False)
```

check the pandas html code in the termnal:

```
print(results.to_html(index=False,escape=False))
```